# Is Colab compliant with Google's HIPAA offering?

Tags: google-colaboratory

If I use Colab and store it's notebooks in the "My Drive" that is included in a company's HIPAA-compliant Google Drive, is that considered fully HIPAA compliant itself?

In the "HIPAA Included Functionality" URL that I found which seems to explain HIPAA-compliant Google services, I don't see Colab listed specifically:

https://workspace.google.com/terms/2015/1/hipaa_functionality.html

However, that URL seems to date back to 2015, which is now six years ago.  It isn't clear to me if things which store their data in Google Drive are automatically considered HIPAA-compliant, or if there is more to compliance than that (for example, perhaps the compute resources also need to be considered).

Any help on my question would be great!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a legal question, not a programming one.